# How to Use Solr leftOuterJoin Query?

Tags: solr

I need to use Solr leftOuterJoin Function.

Normally Use Query "http://localhost:9083/solr/item/select?q=ITEM_NAME:APPLE"

Solr Document leftOuterJoin Example Below

```
leftOuterJoin(
  search(people, q=*:*, fl="personId,name", sort="personId asc"),
  search(pets, q=type:cat, fl="personId,petName", sort="personId asc"),
  on="personId"
)
```

However I don't konw How to make query to use sample

http://localhost:9083/solr/item/select?leftOuterJoin(search(people, q=*:*, fl="personId,name", sort="personId asc"),search(pets, q=type:cat, fl="personId,petName", sort="personId asc"),on="personId")

Not Work

Answer (score 0):

This is [a streaming expression](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/streaming-expressions.html) and not a regular query.

[Streaming expressions are issued against](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/streaming-expressions.html#streaming-requests-and-responses) the `/stream` endpoint:

```
http://localhost:9083/solr/item/stream
```

and with the argument `expr=` to denote your streaming expression:

```
expr=leftOuterJoin(
  search(people, q=*:*, fl="personId,name", sort="personId asc"),
  search(pets, q=type:cat, fl="personId,petName", sort="personId asc"),
  on="personId"
)
```

Comment: Thank for your advice :)